# Asymptotic behavior of the Dirichlet-Laplacian eigenvalues

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, eigenvalues, eigenvector, laplacian

I found in a math book http://www.cambridge.org/dz/academic/subjects/mathematics/differential-and-integral-equations-dynamical-systems-and-co/introduction-partial-differential-equations?format=PB&isbn=9780521613231
a formula which gives the asymptotic behavior of the Laplacian eigenvalues with Dirichlet boundary condition in a bounded domain of $R^n$, this formula is given by [image]

But when we compute explicitly the eigenvalues of the Laplacian in the unit square we find that ${\lambda _{n,m}} =  - {\pi ^2}({n^2} + {m^2})$. I can not see where is the problem in the above formula of the book because for $j=2$ we don't have the same behavior, and there is not a regularity restriction on $\Omega$. Thanks.

Comment: Consider editing the title and author of the book into your question. Also, there is nothing wrong here: note that $n$ in the given formula and $n$ in $\lambda_{m,n}$ refer to different things.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for the answer, can you explain what the authors meant bay $n$ in the above formula?

Comment: $n$ in the formula is the $n$-th eigenvalue, ordered from small to large; let me denote it by $N$; in your formula for $\lambda_{n,m}$ you should combine the indices $n$ and $m$ into a single index $N$ that counts the ordered set of eigenvalues, then you will find equation (9.54), which basically says that in two dimension ($j=2$) the eigenvalues have a constant spacing (because $\lambda_N\propto N$).

Comment: According to your explanation sir, can I conclude that the serie $\sum\limits_n {\frac{1}{{{\lambda _n}}}} $ diverges if the space dimension is greater then 1 ?

Comment: Yes and no (if suitable regularized). Look up the $\zeta$-function of the Laplacian. For instance in Shubin's book on spectral theory and pseudodifferential operators.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, it left one thing more, how can I prove that the serie of the inverse of the of $\lambda_{n,m}$ diverges?